# Can Windows 10 repair media repair a formatted C drive?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, windows-8, boot, gpt

Windows 10 was installed on Drive C. Drive E and F are almost full. I decided to downgrade to Windows 8, and made a bootable USB stick of the same. I'm a linux guy and my windows skills are rusty at best.

I booted using the Windows 8 stick and chose "Custom Install" and formatted my C drive. The installer then notified me that the drive isn't GPT and needs to be converted from MBR to GPT, which apparently requires a complete format. The "Regular" install option (which I glazed over) asks me to run the setup utility from the windows desktop(R.I.P).

Apart from copying my data over to another drive and installing Windows 8 after formatting the drive, the only other options are using Windows 10 recovery media or somehow mimicking the windows desktop to run the installer with the "Regular" option. **Are either of these alternate cases viable? Can Windows 10 repair media "repair" my C drive? Can something start the "Regular" installer without repairing my C drive?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have made a complete clone of your disk to preserve your data ([Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php) works on FAT32, NTFS, and ext4 and is free), you MAY repeat MAY be able to [convert your drive's partition table](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/convert-mbr-to-gpt-disk) from [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) to [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) with [gptgen](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptgen/files/gptgen/v1.0/gptgen-1.0.txt/view), a la:

`gptgen -c -w  \\.\physicaldrive0`
(if **C:** is Drive **0**)

There are commercial products which claim to do it as well.

Alas, using Microsoft's old tool, [diskpart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskpart), which is included with Windows, ever since Win2k, will probably trash your data.  They have a new [MBR2GPT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt) tool available with Windows 10 since Build 1703 which [will convert the partition table](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/mbr2gpt-tool-windows-10), but I don't know if that is available to you.

Comment: Is there any way to convert the C partition into GPT and install windows 8 on it using linux? I've burnt CloneZilla to a thumb drive.

Comment: Install Windows from Linux? No. Convert partition in Linux? Yes with gptgen as above.